# Converted Joomla 2.5 template to 3.0 and now the module positions are not showing

Tags: templates, upgrade, joomla3.0

I recently converted a Joomla 2.5 template to 3.0, the template installed successfully. But the module positions do not work. I am certain that the issue is in the index.php file. the only thing that loads is the logo, but then the rest of the template appears to be inactive. Please explain to me why this is so, or if I have to re-define all the sections of the template again. Also include how the module positions are defined in joomla 3.0 inorder for me to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there changed something between Joomla 2.5 and 3.0 in this regard.
To load a module position in a template, you still use:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" />
```

or in case you want to apply a special chrome:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="html5" />
```

Now in your case, it may be possible that there is a problem within your chrome somewhere and that this is the reason why the logo loads but not the others.
These are defined in `/templates/your_template/html/modules.php`. You may want to have a look at http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1 if you use a removed function there.

Comment: I do not have a modules.php file in my template, as I mentioned this was a Joomla 2.5 template that I converted. However, I see a modules.php file in "Protostar" the default Joomla 3.0 template. Can I just use this one instead or do I need to build my own from scratch?

Comment: If the template doesn't have its own modules.php file, then the one from `/templates/system/html/modules.php` is used. But this one will not generate any errors for sure. You may want to enable the error reporting and check your server error log to see if there are any errors.